# Python Class: overwrite `self`

Tags: python, python-3.x, storage, self, global

In my python script I have *a global storage* (a simple global `dict`) that stores `Processo` objects. It get's filled during the execution of my program. It exists to avoid creating repeated `Processo` objects,  due performance reasons.

So, for the `class Processo` I want verify during its creation if it is already  on the *global storage*.

In that case I just want to copy it to `self`.  I am using `getfromStorage()` for that.

```
class Processo:
    def __init__(self, name, ...): # ... for simplicity
       self.processoname = name
       self = getfromStorage(self)
```

Don't know if it's useful but ...

```
def getfromStorage(processo):
    if processo.processoname in process_storage:
        return process_storage[processo.processoname]
    return processo
```

How do I achieve that? Am I missing something or my design is wrong?

Comment: By the time `.__init__()` gets called, the new instance already exists, and is what the caller of the class is going to receive.  Assigning to `self` is just changing a local variable, it has absolutely no effect outside of the method.  You could try implementing `.__new__()`, instead, but keep in mind that `.__init__()` is still going to be called on the resulting object - you'd need to make sure that it doesn't do anything to overwrite attributes of one of these pre-created objects.

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro: Please google for "Factory Pattern" and "Repository Pattern".

Comment: @jasonharper I found that about `self` somewhere else too, but thank you!! But how to really fill in `self` with some other object?

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro you can't *that doesn't make any sense*, or rather, it isn't useful. Again, `self` is just a local variable that refers the the instance the method was called on. Simply re-binding that local variable has no useful effect for your purposes

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't want to to re-bind the local variable I want to overwrite the entire self class object.

Comment: Will this work?     `self.__dict__ = getfromStorage(self)` With     `getfromStorage(processo)` like using `copy.deepcopy` as `copy.deepcopy(process_storage[processo.processostr].__dict__)` and `copy.deepcopy(processo.__dict__)`

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro: That's technically legal (mildly surprising to me), but it doesn't make singleton objects, it just makes them copy underlying attribute storage (which means the objects are unrelated, not a shared single cached object). Even w/o `copy.deepcopy`, they'd only share the underlying attribute storage (assuming no use of `__slots__`, which would completely break it). That will change behavior in ways that an auto-caching system might not like (e.g. `obj1 is obj2` will be `False`, even if both were constructed such that they should have produced the same cached object).

Comment: thanks @ShadowRanger your point about `singleton objects` is really good, also help me understand the concept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This pattern can't be accomplished reasonably with `__init__`, because `__init__` only *initializes* an already existing object, and you can't change what the caller will get (you can rebind `self`, but that just cuts *you* off from the object being created, the caller has their own separate alias that is unaffected).

The correct way to do this is to override the actual constructor, `__new__`, which allows you to *return* the new instance, which you may or may not create:

```
class Processo:
    def __new__(cls, name, ...): # ... for simplicity
       try:
           # Try to return existing instance from storage
           return getfromStorage(name)
       except KeyError:
           pass

       # No instance existed, so create new object
       self = super().__new__(cls)  # Calls parent __new__ to make empty object

       # Assign attributes as normal
       self.processoname = name

       # Optionally insert into storage here, e.g. with:
       self = process_storage.setdefault(name, self)
       # which will (at least for name of built-in type) atomically get either then newly
       # constructed self, or an instance that was inserted by another thread
       # between your original test and now
       # If you're not on CPython, or name is a user-defined type where __hash__
       # is implemented in Python and could allow the GIL to swap, then use a lock
       # around this line, e.g. with process_storage_lock: to guarantee no races

       # Return newly constructed object
       return self
```

To reduce overhead, I mildly rewrote `getfromStorage`, so it just takes the name and performs lookup, allowing the exception to bubble if it fails:

```
def getfromStorage(processoname):
    return process_storage[processoname]
```

which means that, when a cached instance can be used, no unnecessary `self` object need be freshly constructed.

Note: If you do this, it's usually a good idea not to define `__init__` at all; the construction of an object is done by calling the class's `__new__`, then implicitly calling `__init__` on the result. For cached instances, you wouldn't want them reinitialized, so you want an empty `__init__` (so the cached instance isn't modified by virtue of being retrieved from the cache). Put all `__init__`-like behavior in the code that constructs and returns a new object inside `__new__`, and only execute it for new objects, to avoid this problem.

Comment: Alternatively, you can implement a metaclass `__call__` and do the caching there, which allows your class to define an `__init__` and you don't have to much around with `__new__` and worry about re-initialization

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Downside to that is now you have a metaclass, and therefore inheritance is limited by the potential for metaclass conflicts. There's no real benefit to having a `__init__` if you need a `__new__` anyway (the latter serves double duty admirably), so I'd prefer to keep metaclasses out whenever possible.

Comment: Definitely a reasonable consideration. Honestly, I would almost always just use a factory function here that does the caching, maybe a `classmethod` on the class itself. But then, you have to hope everyone will always use the factory function

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: "Reasonable": When simple patterns like cached instances don't require a heavyweight tool like metaclasses that limits flexibility just to keep using `__init__`. :-) The factory function approach is fine, but as you say, it requires more programmer discipline from consumers of your API.

Comment: Well, it's more so to avoid the possibility of re-initialization if anyone ever mistakenly implements an `__init__`. Using `__new__` is a rather arcane technique that isn't obvious to people who aren't well-versed in Python

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: And metaclasses, let alone metaclass `__call__` overloads, are?

Comment: Well, let me put it this way, I'd be more wary of someone deciding to implement `__init__` despite it not being good because we've implemented `__new__` versus someone seeing `class Foo(metaclass=MetaFoo)` and deciding to muck around with it. But you are right, metaclasses are hardly user-friendly from the perspective of a competent yet new team member

Comment: One could imagine using both `__new__` and `__init__`; `__new__` handles fetching from the cache or creating (but not caching) a new instance, and `__init__` handles *adding* a new instance to the cache. On startup, `__init__` checks if `self` is in the cache: if it is, it returns without doing anything else; otherwise, it adds the object to the cache and proceeds with initializing the object.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you nailed my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The first question I would ask is why method `getfromStorage` is not exposed to the user with the implementation:

```
def getfromStorage(name):
    if name in process_storage:
        return process_storage[name]
    return Processo(name)
```

And `Processo` defined as:

```
class Processo:
    def __init__(self, name, ...): # ... for simplicity
       self.processoname = name
```

This seems like it would solve your problem. But if you do not want to or cannot expose the underlying caching, then:

**Another Way Similar To What You Are Trying To Do**

I believe the pattern that fits your need is the so-called Bridge pattern, also known as the Handle/Body pattern. Quoting from *Design Patterns* by Gamma *et al*, this pattern is used in a variety of circumstances among which is when "you want to share an implementation among multiple objects and ***this fact should be hidden from the client*** or you always want the client to access the actual "body" implementation through the "handle" object for some other reason. The "handle" object keeps a reference to the "body" implementation and delegates all calls to that implementation. Multiple handles can refer to the same body, of course. In the example below, I have used an abstract base class, which really isn't necessary with Python's duck typing.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Processo(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, name): raise NotImplementedError

    @abstractmethod
    def get_name(self): raise NotImplementedError

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self): raise NotImplementedError


class Processo_Handle(Processo): # the handle class
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.processo = getfromStorage(name)

    def get_name(self):
        return self.processo.get_name() # delegate to "body" object

    def foo(self):
        self.processo.foo() # delegate to "body" object
        return self # don't return result of the call to foo because it's the wrong instance (i.e. the body)


class Processo_Body(Processo): # the bodyclass
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def foo(self):
        """ do whatever it takes """
        return self

process_storage = {} # dummy implementation    
def getfromStorage(processoname):
    if processoname in process_storage:
        return process_storage[processoname]
    return Processo_Body(processoname)
```

Comment: The code you've written is Python 2 only (metaclass usage changed in the transition). And getting metaclasses involved here limits utility quite a bit, as it prevents mixins from classes with conflicting metaclasses. And that's ignoring the overhead (runtime performance and maintenance) from all this interface and wrapper stuff.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Your comment forced me to look over my code and I did find some syntax and spelling errors. But after I corrected those, (1) it does compile and execute under Python 3 and, (2) as I said in my answer, the use of using the abstract base class is completely optional (3) this Bridge pattern was only being offered as an alternate to my real first, primary suggestion.

Comment: The part that doesn't work is `__metaclass__ = ABCMeta`, which won't prevent your code from working (Python 3 just ignores it), but will prevent the `abstractmethod` decorators from doing what they're supposed to do (require subclasses to implement the methods). Without that, `Processo` is effectively documentation-only.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks, I have "adjusted" my abstract base class.

Comment: in the end this was simpler than overwritting `__new__` had to rewrite my code after some bugs