# How to restart session after n amount of requests have been made

Tags: python, oop, python-requests

I have a script that tries to scrape data from a website. The website blocks any incoming requests after ~75 requests have already been made to it. I found that resetting a session after 50 requests and sleeping for 30s seems to get around the problem of getting blocked. Now I would like to subclass requests.Session and modify It's behaviour in order so It automatically resets the session when it needs to. Here is my code so far:

```
class Session(requests.Session):
    request_count_limit = 50

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.request_count = 0
    
    def get(self, url, **kwargs):
        if self.request_count == self.request_count_limit:
            self = Session.restart_session()
        response = super().get(url, **kwargs)
        self.request_count += 1
        return response
    
    @classmethod
    def restart_session(cls):
        print('Restarting Session, Sleeping For 20 seconds...')
        time.sleep(20)
        return cls()
```

However, the code above doesn't work. The reason is although I am reassigning self the object itself doesn't change and with that the `request_count` doesn't change as well. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to self is just changing a local variable, it has absolutely no effect outside of the method. You could try implementing .**new**() instead.

Look here: [Python Class: overwrite `self`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60514008/python-class-overwrite-self)